# Find the overlap of two datasets

Tags: r, dplyr

I have two different datasets as I've shown below: df_A and df_B.

```
df_A <- tribble(
  ~book_name, ~sales_id, 
  "A",         1,          
  "B",         2,          
  "C",         3,          
  "D",         4,          
  "E",         5,          
  "F",         3,          
  "G",         8,          
  "H",         6,          
  "I",         7,          
  "J",         7,          
)
```

```
df_B <- tribble(
  ~book_name, ~sales_id, 
  "A",         1,          
  "N",         2,          
  "C",         3,          
  "E",         4,          
  "K",         5,          
  "R",         3,          
  "S",         8,          
  "U",         6,          
  "Z",         7,          
  "Y",         7,          
)
```

Now, I want to see the overlap of these two datasets on book_name. Namely, I want to make a list that shows us the book_name that are both in the datasets and also how similar these two datasets according to the book_name column.

Is there any idea to do this in an accurate way?

Comment: Not sure what is your expected output but `inner_join(df_A, df_B, by = "book_name")` would give you books which are present in both the dataset.

Comment: Did you try to use `*_join` functions? If I understood your question correctly, semi_join should do the job.

Answer (score 0):

You can do an inner join between the two dataframes which automatically gives you the intersection between the two dataframes.

This should do the trick,

```
library(dplyr)

# Creating first data frame
df_A <- tribble(
  ~book_name, ~sales_id, 
  "A",         1,          
  "B",         2,          
  "C",         3,          
  "D",         4,          
  "E",         5,          
  "F",         3,          
  "G",         8,          
  "H",         6,          
  "I",         7,          
  "J",         7,          
)

# Creating second data frame
df_B <- tribble(
  ~book_name, ~sales_id, 
  "A",         1,          
  "N",         2,          
  "C",         3,          
  "E",         4,          
  "K",         5,          
  "R",         3,          
  "S",         8,          
  "U",         6,          
  "Z",         7,          
  "Y",         7,          
)

# Joining between the two dataframes to get the common values between the two
result <-
  df_A %>%
  inner_join(df_B, by = "book_name")
```

Comment: Thank you for highlighting this. I have considered your feedback and accordingly edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a base R solution, where maybe you can use `intersect()`, i.e.,

```
overlap <- subset(df_A,book_name %in% intersect(book_name,df_B$book_name))
```

such that

```
> overlap
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  book_name sales_id
  <chr>        <dbl>
1 A                1
2 C                3
3 E                5
```